# Microsoft Access Multi Value

Tags: ms-access

I have a Multi value table with ItemCatergory, Item Description, Unit and Rate, Linked to a table with the full list of records.

I wish that when the multi values (Item catergory) are selected then they will auto display in the next fields[image].

i have previously done this with combo boxes, but not with multi value, i now get a error in the code, which in theory should load the values into the text boxes. 
[image]

Comment: It is not entirely evident what you are endeavoring to accomplish with this inquiry. Would you kindly clarify your problem a bit more clearly? 
Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example [(MCVE link)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to more plainly explain what you are attempting to achieve. Also, would you kindly clarify what your full error is (all we can see is that you placed a stop in your code)?

Comment: A multi-valued combo box contains multiple values. Which one do you want in that text box? Also, using the .Colum property can lead to trouble. In general, multi-valued combo boxes are trouble, and list boxes are more well-documented and exhibit less buggy behavior.